# How to grep and print only specific attributes of an ansible module

Tags: python, ansible, module

I am trying to access information from the `community.vmware.vmware_host_disk_info` module. From this module I need to grep for `canonical_name` and then `device_ctd_list` of that canonical name alone.

I tried using:

```yaml
- name: Gather info about vmhbas of an ESXi Host
  community.vmware.vmware_host_disk_info:
    hostname: '{{ vhostname }}'
    username: '{{ vusername }}'
    password: '{{ vpassword }}'
    validate_certs: false
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: host_vmhbas

- name: Printing host vmhba
  debug:
    msg: " {{ host_vmhbas }} "

- name: Trimming
  debug:
     msg: "{{ community.vmware.vmware_host_disk_info['results'][0]['current'][0]['canonical_name']['attributes']['device_ctd_list']}}"
```

But I need like `'device_ctd_list': ['xx:xx:xx:xx'], 'canonical_name': 'xxxx.1223445'`

Comment: Can you update your question with the full output of `host_vmhbas`? Without the data structure and content I am not sure how one could answer this.

Answer (score 0):

According the documentation [`vmware_host_disk_info` module – Gathers information about disks attached to given ESXi host/s](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_host_disk_info_module.html) I've created a test data file out of the [Return Values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_host_disk_info_module.html#return-values) `Sample`.

**`sample.json`**

```json
{
  "192.168.0.182": [
    {
      "canonical_name": "naa.6000c296ed6217bd61df35622eb21a3a",
      "capacity_mb": 4096,
      "device_path": "/vmfs/devices/disks/naa.6000c296ed6217bd61df35622eb21a3a",
      "device_type": "disk",
      "device_ctd_list": [
        "vmhba0:C0:T1:L0"
       ],
      "disk_uid": "key-vim.host.ScsiDisk-02000000006000c296ed6217bd61df35622eb21a3a566972747561",
      "display_name": "Local VMware Disk (naa.6000c296ed6217bd61df35622eb21a3a)"
    },
    {
      "canonical_name": "naa.6000c2968ad7142d93faae527fe8822b",
      "capacity_mb": 204800,
      "device_path": "/vmfs/devices/disks/naa.6000c2968ad7142d93faae527fe8822b",
      "device_type": "disk",
      "device_ctd_list": [
        "vmhba0:C0:T3:L0"
        ],
      "disk_uid": "key-vim.host.ScsiDisk-02000000006000c2968ad7142d93faae527fe8822b566972747561",
      "display_name": "Local VMware Disk (naa.6000c2968ad7142d93faae527fe8822b)"
    }
  ]
}
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Load sample test data
    include_vars:
      file: sample.json
      name: host_vmhbas

  - name: Gather IP from sample test data
    set_fact:
      IP: "{{ host_vmhbas.keys() | first }}"

  - name: Requested result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.device_ctd_list | first }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.canonical_name }}"
    loop: "{{ host_vmhbas[IP] }}"
```

will result into

```yaml
TASK [Requested result] *****************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=naa.6000c296ed6217bd61df35622eb21a3a) =>
  msg: vmhba0:C0:T1:L0
ok: [localhost] => (item=naa.6000c2968ad7142d93faae527fe8822b) =>
  msg: vmhba0:C0:T3:L0
```